# Getting an IndexOutofBoundsException when implementing delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITextField in my application that I want to function like a calculator.  I need it to have the default value of 0.00, and as the user enters digits, the numbers move from right to left, replacing the zeroes in 0.00 one digit at a time, and the application should be smart enough to add commas (,) after every three digits.  To do this, I am implementing the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {}
```

as follows:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]]
    isEqualToString:@""])
    return YES;

NSString *previousValue = [[[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
NSString *modifiedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",previousValue,string];
modifiedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[modifiedValue substringToIndex:modifiedValue.length-2],[modifiedValue substringFromIndex:modifiedValue.length-2]];//this is the line that is causing the error

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
modifiedValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[modifiedValue floatValue]]];

textField.text = modifiedValue;
return NO;
```

}

However, I am getting the following error:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

This error was thrown the moment I tried to enter a number in the textfield.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this bit right here:

```
[modifiedValue substringToIndex:modifiedValue.length-2]
```

seems to assume that the length of the string is at least 2.

Which is probably isn't, at least when the user is typing his/her first character into an empty text field.

How about putting a length check around the whole thing, only doing the guts of the "`shouldChangeCharactersInRange`" method if the length is greater than two characters?